# How can we get the trimmed video by time frames in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession, video-editing

I have a requirement to trim a recorded video/prerecorded video by frames. I got stuff for `AVCatureSession` to get it. But I am not able to identify how take first time frame and second time frame to get the video from the selection. So that I can get the trimmed video between first and second time frame.
Please guide me how to achieve it. 
Running code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use AVMutableComposition to do this task
Code compatible with Swift 5

```
extension AVAsset {      
    func assetByTrimming(startTime: CMTime, endTime: CMTime) throws -> AVAsset {
        let duration = CMTimeSubtract(endTime, startTime)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, duration: duration)

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        do {
            for track in tracks {
                let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: track.mediaType, preferredTrackID: track.trackID)
                compositionTrack?.preferredTransform = track.preferredTransform
                try compositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: CMTime.zero)
            }
        } catch let error {
            throw TrimError("error during composition", underlyingError: error)
        }

        return composition
    }
```

}